# Are Google-Fit API available on Android TV?

Tags: google-play-services, android-tv, google-fit

My sample app using GoogleFit API of GooglePlayServices runs on Android mobile (using Android-M) but the same sample app gives error as API_UNAVAILABLE on Android TV (using Android-M) even though PlayServices version is latest version on TV.
My intention is to only to READ the Google-fit data.

Is it so that device like TV might not have health/fitness sensors and hence GooglePlayServices does not enable Google-Fit API (even though an application might be only interested in reading data)?

Any pointers available on this on how to enable GoogleFit APIs on Android TV?

**EDIT1**

Tried with 365 Body Workout apk  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.peirr.workout.play&hl=en  on AndroidTV having latest GooglePlayServices [11.5.09 (836-164803921)] and found that it does not work as indicated in the below picture [image]

Comment: What version of Google Play Services is installed on the Android TV?

Comment: Version 11.5.09 (836-164803921) on Android TV

Comment: I think you can as this blog - [365 Body Workout brings fitness to your Android TV](https://www.androidcentral.com/365-body-workout-brings-fitness-your-android-tv), this is one example of Google fit integration in Android TV. I'm not sure about the specific details on how to implement, but atleast you now know that it is possible. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Rebot for pointing out to the app. But found that App is not connecting to GooglePlayServices. Have edited the problem with the details.